# SQL: computation of depth inside stock's glass

Tags: sql, sqlite

Little description of task:

- Need to get `total` of `base` if we will selling `coin_quantity` of `coin` to the `market`.
- By default, this example means, that `market` is `coin+"_"+base`. No flip case.
- For simplification, there is only one case(action): `selling` / `ask`.

python:

```
def get_depth_price( db_cursor, coin_quantity, coin, market ):
            sql_command = "SELECT * FROM '" + market + "' WHERE type=1"
            db_cursor.execute( sql_command )
            bids = sorted([ i for i in  db_cursor.fetchall() ], \
                           key = lambda k: k[3], reverse = True )
            tmp_quantity = float( coin_quantity )
            tmp_total = 0
            for bid in bids:
                    if tmp_quantity > bid[4]:
                            tmp_total += bid[4] * bid[3]
                            tmp_quantity -= bid[4]
                    else:
                            tmp_total += tmp_quantity * bid[3]
                            tmp_quantity = 0
                            break
            return tmp_total
```

Where market data looks like:

```
# echo "SELECT * from 'DOGE_BTC' WHERE type=1 
        ORDER BY price DESC;" | sqlite3 big.db

6f827564d88ddd0d99a9f976ac384a3f|0|1|5.0e-07|374365.08
1f696fea1270c07d9d4217e47ad40d3c|0|1|4.9e-07|1337443.42857
b9bee0a3bc2d4b241383062f06569b54|0|1|4.8e-07|465618.375
716cb29e0f5fe4742de73302e5b88250|0|1|4.7e-07|197560.659574
3189ed55c60530014892c6a3fce673e8|0|1|4.6e-07|115757.521739
cf19858241fb25de9095160b1704ef44|0|1|4.5e-07|237807.133333
f53642c0e7d5074daaa2b324e82483c5|0|1|4.4e-07|16112.6818182
ee8fb3f5255fb0ef8c157becb6a8c539|0|1|4.3e-07|22581.0697674
###  (0)id ----^       (1)self---^ ^    ^-(3)price      ^
###     (2)type(ask=0/bid=1)-------+       (4)quantity--+
```

Methinks, that python script - is very very slow thing against sql.

However, I can't create similar on the sql language.

How to replace full function of `get_depth_price` by sql-query?

How to create on sql similar to `if tmp_quantity > bid[4]` / `then` / `else` ?

Comment: Did you cryptograph your question before publish???

Comment: No. No any ambiguous background. My Engrish is still poor, Sorry. I'm practicing...

Comment: Just kidding, but can't realy understand your task...

Comment: For example, such call `get_depth_price(  db_cursor, 1000000, "DOGE", "DOGE_BTC" )` - will using not only highest price, but will using also `depth` of market. It will truncate all highest bids, until quantity is not end.

Comment: You can get the sorted list from the DB. But it looks as if this `tmp_quantity` stuff cannot be done directly in SQLite.

Comment: Although it can be expressed in Sqlite, i don't thing it would be faster due to triangle join needed to evaluate running total of quantity. Sqlite has no analytic functions which could help.

Comment: Serg & CL, I can't believe it. Must be a hook-hack-way.